# Github: Why does the new changes appeared on the file but not on the website?

Tags: git, vue.js, github, web

I am trying to edit the content(e.g. change a few word) of a file from the repo below.(i am the co-owner). This owner use vue to create the website. When i added the changes, it is reflected on the file but not on the website. I try several methods: edit directly from git, edit on my local branch and pushed it to remote repo. etc... but it is not working.(FYI, i am a beginner at web development and git). Before vue is used, everything works fine

repo:
https://github.com/busase/busase.org

git command:

git clone https://github.com/busase/busase.org.git

git add src/views/EBoard.vue

git commit -m 'new change'

git push -u origin master

result:
Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 528 bytes | 264.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), completed with 3 local objects.
remote:
remote: GitHub found 3 vulnerabilities on busase/busase.org's default branch (1 high, 1 moderate, 1 low). To find out more, visit:
remote:      https://github.com/busase/busase.org/security/dependabot
remote:
To https://github.com/busase/busase.org.git
885fddb..f3ffadb  master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'

Comment: The owner of the git repo might not have setup automated deployment - when ever the master branch changes [CI/CD](https://github.com/features/actions) is fired which runs certain checks and then deploys the new change to the server (a server in the cloud, maybe). *Ask the owner of the repo to push your changes to production*

Answer (score 0):

If there is no autodeployment, the repo owner needs to push changes to the server.
So after updating server you can see changes.

Comment: but it seems, like auto-deployment only works for html/css for the owner. is there a way to get around with tht?

Comment: You can deploy whatever you want, so you can configure your autodeployment, i am not master in that thing, but i guess you need to talk to owner to deploy your changes into production.